# How do I add SQL to a coldfusion Query

Tags: coldfusion

I am creating a new query object with

```
<cfset LOCAL.Query = QueryNew( "" ) />
```

I am then building up a complicated data set from an array that was passed in.
My query object looks perfect.

How do I then add the SQL text and datasource to the query so that I can execute it?

I am going to be inserting the data using a passed in datasource and insert statement.

Comment: You will need another query to insert the data.  You will be looping through this complicated data set you just created.

Comment: Thank you, I suspected that but thought that maybe the query object was a little more complete and I that I would be able to just add the datasource and SQL properties to it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, in order to use SQL and retrieve data from your query object you will use CFQUERY.  Instead of a 'datasource' attribute you will use 'dbtype="query"'.  The table name of the query will be your query object.  For example:

```
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="myQry">
   SELECT * FROM LOCAL.Query
</cfquery>
```

You cannot add new records with an INSERT statement.  You must use the function: QUERYADDROW() and, possibly, QUERYSETCELL().

For instance, :

```
<cfset queryAddRow(LOCAL.Query, {"id"=1,"title"="Hello world"})>
```

Or:

```
<cfset queryAddRow(LOCAL.Query)>
<cfset querySetCell(LOCAL.Query, "id", "1")>
<cfset querySetCell(LOCAL.Query, "title", "Hello world")>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dan answered the question for me.

I was hoping to be able to modify the query object and add the datasource and SQL but after much study I was unable to do so.

The correct answer is Dan´s comment about a new query object.

Comment: You might not even need the original query object.  As you loop through the array to create a complicated data set, you can incorporate your insert query then, either in addition to, or instead of adding rows to your query object.